# Adding a column to a matrix as part of a function in R

Tags: r, function, matrix

I am brand new to R and I am trying my hand at creating functions for the first time. I am trying to make a function that will give me regression coefficients, an R-square and an Adjusted R-square value where x is a matrix of values and y is a vector. I had no problem making the basic equations, but I need a way to make the function add a column of ones to the x matrix so that the user doesn't have to put it in. In other words, my function works great if I make my first column in the matrix c(1), but I want that to be done by the function. I know there must e an extremely simple answer to this but I have tried everything I can think of and looked at many different questions but I couldn't figure it out (because I am so new at this, a lot of the information I find about R online is  really hard for me to understand). Anyways, any help is greatly appreciated. I will answer any clarification questions to best of my ability. 
I have been using the following sample dataset/R functions to test it out:

```
x<-cbind(c(4,6,8,10),c(5,3,6,7))

y<-c(2,6,9,4)

fit.lm<-lm(y~x)

summary(fit.lm)
```

If I can just add that column of ones, my function will give me back the same values as the functions above....My code so far:

```
mylm<-function(y,x)

{

betahat<-solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y

yhat<-predict(lm(y~x))

Rsquare<-1-((sum((yhat-y)^2))/sum((y-mean(y))^2))

AdjRsquare<-1-((sum((yhat-y)^2))/sum((y-mean(y))^2))%*%((length(y)-1)/(length(y)-length(betahat)))

results<-list(B=betahat,R2=Rsquare,R2A=AdjRsquare)

return(results)

}

mylm(y,x)
```

Comment: If you are using `lm` to fit the model in your function, why are you computing `betahat` using by hand?

Comment: @HSUstudent Welcome to SO.  I'm guessing you're doing this task to understand a bit about programming in R as related to statistics.  I have undertaken similar tasks.  May I suggest that often less is more.  You have a lot of text describing the problem and code for a function.  You don't really want us to fix the function (there's a stack site for that) you want a specific task.  So I suggest you provide a minimal example of that task and provide just enough context to make us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased.. You want a column of all 1s where? To make a vector of 1s: rep(1,length(vector.of.length.i.want.to.cbind.to))

Comment: you could just define `x <- cbind(1,x)` within your function to create a design matrix including an intercept term.

Comment: @Mnel, I think that's what I've suggested in the reduced solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer but doesn't answer your problem exactly.  Some assembly required.  If this doesn't answer your question please reformat your question:

```
mylm <- function(x){
    cbind(1, x)
}

mylm(x)
```